# .NET Console Playing Sounds While Writing Certains Strings

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a .NET script implemented as a console application. During execution it writes debug information to the console. During the script, the application occasionally beep several times in succession. Looking closer it seems to happen everytime certain characters are printed.

Is there any special characters that would cause the system to beep when read into memory or printed to the screen in .NET?

The characters resembles this:

> ×¨×>×'×ª ×"×¡×o×'×¡  ×¦'××¦'× ××?×'×?  ×o××'×" ×'×¨××z× ×T×" 
>   ×"×z××¤×¢  ×o×z×¦××? ×?×ª ×-××©×"  ×''×¡×T×§×" ×¤×¨×"×T×T×-  ×"×ª××?×¨
>   ×'×z×'×"  ×"×?×-×T×§××Y

and this

> é>┼ å╬¶æ%<è?½ç½' å¼æ-°ç-'å>¢ é>┼ å«£çº¢é?╬ä¸S å®³ç^¶ä»╬äº é>┼
>   å°?å^?è¯^ç-. ä¸ºè§?å┼·è¡ é>┼ è?½çY³ç< æ<> è¿«ä¼-å±^æo é>┼ æ­£æ^'åSªåS>
>   è?¥æ'ä¼-äºº é>┼ ä¸ºåS©å┼·è¡? æ­£æ^'å?-ä¼ é>┼ å┼·è¡?æ^?åSY å®Oæ^?ä»»åS
>   é>┼ å"¿å­?è¢«æ?? è"¡äº¬ç<'æ? é>┼ é"?æ%<æ??äºº è¯?æ?®ç¡®å╬
>   é>┼ã??æ- æƒ.åZYæ~¯ æ^?å®¶å?Z é>┼ è<¥é£zæ"¯æO? è¿½å'½å¼?è§ é>┼
>   æ- æƒ.æ­£æ^' å?'çZ°çoYç> é>┼ è<¥é£zå¤±æ~Z é"?æ%<å¿ƒç- é>┼

But I haven't gotten them to beep by trying to write them to the console manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that you are printing a character that maps to the ASCII Bell character:  [MSDN Blog on the issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/01/04/1411080.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The console will beep when an ASCII BEL character (0x07) is output. Try:

```
Console.Write('\x07');
```

You will not see that character displayed on the screen.